# Avoid newline removal on "forEach", "filter", etc. in TypeScript / JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, typescript, prettier

I am using [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier), and on the whole, love it.

However, there is one type of transformation that I disagree with.  Suppose I am writing some transformation to an array, doing a `filter`, `forEach`, etc.  If I were writing it manually, I would write it as follows (real code sample):

```
// ...
snippets
    .filter(s => s.script && s.name)
    .forEach(s => {
        const namespace = transformSnippetName(s.name);
        // ...
    });
```

Note that each of my "top-level" operations (`filter`, `forEach`) are on a separate line, which in my opinion really helps readability.

Now, with Prettier, it combines the `.filter` and `.forEach` to be on the same line:

```
// ...
snippets.filter(s => s.script && s.name).forEach(s => {
    const namespace = transformSnippetName(s.name);
    // ...
});
```

I find this harmful to readability, for two reasons:

1. The `forEach` sort of gets lost in a quick perusal of the code.  I can't visually identify it.
2. The body of the `forEach` becomes one level under-indented, making it visually unclear what `const namespace = ...` is unless you look at it more closely.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening (or at least, prevent prettier from removing my manual formatting on blocks like these, once I've decided to arrange it like this)?  I tried to search for something in the [options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html), but nothing stood out.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't thinks so.  Take a look at this issue that is trying to do almost exactly what you are trying to do: [Keep short promise chains indented #3594](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3594).  The project seems to be of the opinion that as much as possible should be put on one line.

Comment: Irritatingly, you could try setting `--range-start` and `--range-end` to `0`.  See: [this link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEB6VACAdDgOlAZygEsAHUuGA-DW7AM2IBt4AnACgIwF4A+DAlgJhWZGBgBkEgVigBDALZwAlDTpZ6EVgFE5YABace-YGrp1IhcfKUFSeuDwwxWcwptYKAyiXKUAcopwnLJBygDcZuYY6Nh4UOYAvhEgADQgEKQwxNAEyKByrKwQAO4ACoUIeShyAG4QxAAmaSAARq5gANaUXvZgxFAA5sguAK5w6QMEcKwwZa6DCnLI9HJM0+kAVgQAHgBCHd0wXkEAMgNwK2sbIPas06zIbXKtAJ5M0C2korAA6k0wfTIAAcAAZ0t8INNfq5SE9vnAHrVLulWHAAI6jYho+ZyRbLJCrdYTEDTBTEEascbpAgDQZMOAARVGEHgV2J6RgL3+jUByAATJzXMw6QBhCAKJZPKDQFEgUbTAAqL2qRJuriGcC8XNmyHBIA1gzg2igzSQoMSiSAA)

Comment: @zero298, thanks for confirming.  Bummer.  For the `--range-start`, that just makes the file not be prettier-ified, right?  That's a overkill relative to what I'm trying to do.  Though perhaps a "don't-touch-this-portion" sort of comment (like tslint has a "disable-next-line") could be a stopgap solution, if I could inject it straight into the code (and on multiple blocks per code), though still rather un-ideal...